# React-Native White screen after starting debugger on ios simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I am developing in react-native using Visual Studio Code and I have installed the following extension: React Native Tools https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsmobile.vscode-react-native

This extension, allows me to add a configuration in the launch.json file that is used by the debugger to run a configuration and in order to debug on the ios platform, I have added a configuration for ios and also added another one called Attach to packager.

I have started the debugger trying out both of these two configurations but both of them are starting the application on the ios simulator but nothing is showing on my screen and I have put a button and a Text which will show a number incremented every time I push the button.

I don't know what am I doing wrong, because I can't debug my application on an ios simulator.

Started ios debugger configuration
[image]

This is my debug configuration file:
[image]

My package.json file:
[image]

Comment: Is your app component registered ? Like this : `AppRegistry.registerComponent('<App name>', () => App);`

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp Yes, it is registered like that.

Answer (score 0):

touch the home button and click again on the app window